tensorflow model not loading after changing file name
When I change the file name the model does not load correctly.
The filename when the model was trained is 044.weights.h5 and when I load this model using
weak_learner = weighted_unet_model()
weak_learner.load_weights(weight_path)

It works good. But when copy the model and paste it with a new name it doesn't work although everything is the same except the file path pointing to the new location.
The md values are also same
% md5 ~/Downloads/044.weights.h5

MD5 (~/Downloads/044.weights.h5) = 01be4b0bcb4f08ab471dbfcfd6edc842
% md5 ~/Desktop/model_checkpoints_hexa.h5 
MD5 (~/Desktop/model_checkpoints_hexa.h5) = 01be4b0bcb4f08ab471dbfcfd6edc842

One possible reason is the model was trained on a ubuntu system and I'm using a macos tensorflow version. But that should mean the error will occur in loading the model if the name was not changed but that is not the case here
My tensorflow version in mac is
tensorflow                         2.16.1
tensorflow-macos                   2.16.1

Error I get when executing code is:
ValueError: Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file. 
Model expected 37 layers, found 0 saved layers.


Solved it by loading and saving the model in new path and using that path
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from models.model_arch import weighted_unet_model

def save_model_with_new_weights(original_weight_path, new_model_path):
    # Initialize the model
    weak_learner = weighted_unet_model()
    
    # Load the weights from the original path
    weak_learner.load_weights(original_weight_path)
    
    # Save the model with weights to the new path
    weak_learner.save(new_model_path, save_format='h5')
    print(f"Model saved with weights at {new_model_path}")

# Example usage
original_weight_path = '~/Downloads/044.weights.h5'
new_model_path = '~/Desktop/model_checkpoints_hexa.h5'
save_model_with_new_weights(original_weight_path, new_model_path)

